# Asking about adding text beside checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

This box is for filtering the content on a page. I have downloaded this check box from a website and tried to add a text beside it but I can't. The text keep appearing at the same position of the checkbox.

```
       <div class="roundedOne">

                        <input class="swiftfilter" type="checkbox" data-container=".isotope-filter" data-search-in=".grid_6" value="france" data-child=".titledayarchivetour p" data-child-only="true" id="roundedOne" name="check" /> 
                        <label for="roundedOne">CHOOSE FRANCE</label> 


    </div>

.roundedOne {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;
    float: left;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.roundedOne label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.roundedOne label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #00bf00;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.roundedOne label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.roundedOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `width` from `.roundedOne` element and `position:absolute;` from `label`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/o5p88oqs/)

Comment: @kkat Is this helpful?

Comment: @kkat What do you want to be?

Comment: I want it to be like " O choose france "

Comment: Can you post an image which is shown your desire situation?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the situation right now  below the codes. I want the text stay in the same line on the right side of the circle.

Comment: Hey! That's much better! I even like that more than the circle checkbox. Thanks lot!!!!! :D